# Alignment using Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using constraints Space between the green-view and blue-view changed depend upon the screen size. I am using **Vertical Spacing** between green-view and blue-view space is equal for all screens. but I exactly displayed Space between **green-view and blue-view** changes depends upon the screen sizes using constraints.

[image]

How Can i fix the problem?

Comment: Add UIView as spacer where you need spaces and add width and height of the spacer according to the main view, so ultimately the width and height of the spaces will change with main view and thus the spaces.

Comment: Don't understand sir. please can you explain me sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i could understand from your problem, i am giving you below 4 screenshots containing constraints to all 3 views respectively. Last screenshot contains constraints on 1st view's proportional width.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rahul I am understand.But inside the view adding two textfields. How to align space between two textfields inside view changes depends upon the screen sizes using constraints.

Comment: If you understood for your previous querry, please upvote. and for ur next question about textfields in a single view. i guess you are trying to change space between two textfields depending on the size of the screen. For that, you will need to keep the height and width of your textfields constant and set leading, top, bottom and trailing constraints on both textfields. i hope it helped

Comment: I will try sir but Alignment is missing sir

Comment: send me screenshot of constraints you have applied.